# Android Designing Layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, programmatically-created

[image]

How can I make this layout in android programmatically.

I want just an idea not whole coding thing.

Comment: why the image is not showing? You anyone see the image this problem is just with me?

Comment: I can see the Image. But you should explain it a bit more. Which parts are layout elements, what is static picture? Almost everything is possible with a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Actually I don't know how to add these type of parameters, android:layout_alignBottom, android:layout_alignLeft etc

Comment: you need to set them with `addRule()` in `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer but not the direct answer. This is what I personally do to create complex layout programatically.

Create the same layout in XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/some_big_image" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#DD000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now start from **top parent** to **child**.

```
    RelativeLayout mParent = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mParent.setLayoutParams(mParentParams);

    ImageView mBigImageView = new ImageView(this);
    mBigImageView.setLayoutParams(mParentParams);
    mParent.addView(mBigImageView);
```

As you **practice** you can directly code the same without creating xml.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Idea:

1. Create a `RelativeLayout` which contains one `ImageView` and two `TextView` which is aligned bottom
2. set the alpha of the `RelativeLayout` to adjust the transparency

Comment: Actually I don't know how to add these type of parameters, android:layout_alignBottom, android:layout_alignLeft etc.

Comment: @Yawar Please have a look on this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

which will give you some basic idea

Answer (score 0):

You can have one relative layout which contain one image view for big image and below it one more linear layout containing image and text as "pearl Continental ..." and background of liner layout should be 50-60% transparent. 
Create the background for LL using shapes. and set it as align bottom of parent (relative) layout.
Hope this helps you

Comment: Actually I don't know how to add these type of parameters, android:layout_alignBottom, android:layout_alignLeft etc

Comment: Its better to create layout in xml and then inflate where you need. after inflating set the required values to each items

Comment: Also one sample is provided above

Comment: actually I have 3 views in view pager control, layout of all three are different from each other. And I'm searching something what you have suggested but couldn't find anything helpful. That's why doing it programatically.

Comment: so that i can check using switch statement and make my own view programmatically.

Comment: if you have multiple views to display in view pager then you need to identify which one to display in adapter class and then inflate the respective view in adapter. So the same will be update in viewpager.